# How to fix my if/else statement Java

Tags: java

I am pretty new to the java language and tried to run a simple text based program where once you push 1 or 0 it will either continue the story or stop it. What I can't figure out is if I run this portion of code below and I select the wrong answer it bypasses my if statement.

```
    package game;
import java.util.Scanner;
class chase {
public static void main (String args[]){

    int answer1;
    answer1 = 1;

    Scanner chase = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("You hear a noise form a house you walk by. What do you     do?");
    System.out.println("Press 1 to enter the house. Press 0 to run away like a panzy");

    chase.nextLine();

    if (answer1 == 1){
        System.out.println("Good Choice!");
        }else{
        System.out.println("You ran away and was crushed by a falling pig");
        System.out.println("Try again!");
    }

    }

}
```

What I tried to do was once you push 1 it says "Good Choice!" and once you push 0 it runs the else statement. But every time I push 0 it says "Good Choice!"

I don't know what I did wrong. 
Please help.

Comment: What does nextLine() actually do?  I don't see the implementation.  As far as i can tell nothing ever assigns to answer1, so why would it ever change?

Comment: also.. *were* crushed by a falling pig :)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is here:

```
chase.nextLine();
```

You should read a number into `answer1` instead of just reading a line and throwing it away:

```
answer1 = chase.nextInt();
```

That will also make it so you don't need the `answer1 = 1;` line anymore. Since you were just ignoring the line of data you read in, that meant you never changed the value of `answer1`, so it was always `1` no matter what you typed.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you are ever assigning the input to answer1, and since it has an initial value of 1 it will always be true.

Answer (score 2):

you're setting the value of answer1 equal to 1 with this line:

```
answer1 = 1;
```

and never changing it based on the input from your question. Thus `answer` is always equal to 1 and your `else` is ever reached.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 'chase' variable the wrong way, and in this case, 'answer1' initialization is not necessary.

Try this.

```
answer1 = chase.nextInt();
```

Then proceed with your if else statement just like you did in your code.

Comment: I changed it to answer1 = chase.nextInt(); but it wants me to create a method.

Comment: @CHASE write answer1 = chase.nextInt(); AFTER Scanner chase = new Scanner(System.in);